# How can i open the keyboard on android in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqgZdr

**CODE HTML:**

```
<button id="btn">OPEN INPUT</button>
<input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Demo search" class="input-text">
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
#search{
  display:none;
}
```

**CODE jQuery:**

```
jQuery("#btn").on('click', function(){
  jQuery('#search').show();
   jQuery('#search').trigger('click');
});
```

Please open this example on your phone.

What i want is to open the android keyboard when the user clicks on the button.

This example should work on both Iphone and Android.

I tried to simulate a click on the search input but it seems it does not work ... can you help me solve this problem please?

**UPDATE:**

I've just changed the initial example to try a new method, but it does not seem to work either.

**CODE HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Demo search" class="input-text">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
jQuery("button").on('click', function(){
   jQuery('#search').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android pulls up keyboard whenever text input field is in focus.**

Try like this:

```
    jQuery('#search').focus();
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqgZdr  I tried to do what you say, I modified the example a little bit and tell me why the function of .focus () does not work;

Comment: The problem is that the modal has not finished animating when you call .focus();
Here is the proper code:

jQuery("button").on('click', function(){
   setTimeout(()=>{jQuery('#search').focus()},300)
});

Comment: ok but this .focus () does not work on iphone, What can be replaced so it works on the iphone?

Comment: You asked for Android... Try putting  event.preventDefault(); in your click handler like this:

jQuery("button").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
   setTimeout(()=>{jQuery('#search').focus()},300)
});

Comment: I said above that it should work on both Iphone and Android.
Code I put it but it seems nothing changes.